# Importing Fonts into an Angular App

Tags: css, angular, fonts, webfonts

I'm trying to import the Font "Montserrat" into my Angular4 project but it simply resets to standard.

Here's my style.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700");

.fancyFont {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
```

And my friend.component.html

```
<p class="fancyFont">Look at my Fanciness</p>
```

Comment: also you mentioned css, is it scss or css?

Comment: Are you sure your CSS file has loaded in the browser? Depending on how you're building your app, you may need to reference it in a `link` tag or include it in your webpack config.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I'm using CSS

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy My CSS file is loading. I can add other changes like color and padding to .fancyFont which will impact the text, just no font-family change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

I imported the from google fonts like this:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700");
```

Which includes two different weights, 500 and 700.
By telling the CSS which font-weight I wanted to use it began to work.

```
.fancyFont {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how that url looks like.

```
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/BYPM-GE291ZjIXBWrtCweiyNCiQPWMSUbZmR9GEZ2io.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/BYPM-GE291ZjIXBWrtCwevfgCb1svrO3-Ym-Rpjvnho.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/BYPM-GE291ZjIXBWrtCweteM9fzAXBk846EtUMhet0E.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcnv4bDVR720piddN5sbmjzs.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcjrEaqfC9P2pvLXik1Kbr9s.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Montserrat Bold'), local('Montserrat-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v10/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcmaVI6zN22yiurzcBKxPjFE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

If you look at the `local(...)` sections within the content, you can see there are specific `font-family` names for each `font-weight`s (500 & 700) present. So try to specify the `font-family` names instead of generically calling them as `Montserrat` like, `'Montserrat-Medium'` or `'Montserrat-Bold'`. See if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Im fairly sure the fact that the font family is declared as just 'Montserrat' means this answer is wrong

Comment: @amal The `@font-face` code above works for me but can you please tell me how you generated this with unicode-range, as i am new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way font awesome added there fonts into the scss file. Maybe you have to consider this way to do that.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=#{$fa-version}');
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=#{$fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff2'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=#{$fa-version}') format('woff'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=#{$fa-version}') format('truetype'),
    url('#{$fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=#{$fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
//  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```